# Link a Span or Cursor in between plots with Bokeh in Python

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I would like a cursor that is linked between to plots in Bokeh.  So if I move my cursor on one plot, an equivalent line shows up on an adjacent plot.  I haven't figured out how to do it with the built in cursor tool.  So my current solution is to draw a line on each plot that shares a source.  Then when I hover over either plot, the source is updated.

I have 2 issues with this method:
1. It seems like a workaround
2. Currently the lines are finite length. I would like the line to be infinite, so no matter how the graph is resized, the line runs off the edge.  Currently the line I draw is finite. The right way to draw an infinite horizontal line is a Span annotation, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to pass/update the Span location through my callback.  See my code below.

```
from bokeh.io import gridplot, show, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Span


output_notebook()

x = list(range(11))
y1 = x
y2 = [10 - i for i in x]


source = ColumnDataSource({'x0': [0], 'y0': [2], 'x1': [10], 'y1': [2]})

# create a new plot
s1 = figure(width=250, plot_height=250, tools="", title=None)
cr1 = s1.circle(x, y1, size=10, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
sr1 = s1.segment(x0='x0', y0='y0', x1='x1', y1='y1', color='red', alpha=1, line_width=1, source=source, )
sp1 = Span(location=source.data['y0'][0], dimension='width', line_color='green') 
s1.renderers.extend([sp1,])

# create another one
s2 = figure(width=250, height=250, title=None)
cr2 = s2.triangle(x, y1, size=10, color="firebrick", alpha=0.5)
sr2 = s2.segment(x0='x0', y0='y0', x1='x1', y1='y1', color='red', alpha=1, line_width=1, source=source, )

# put all the plots in an HBox
p = gridplot([[s1,s2],[]])

code = """
var data = {'x0': [], 'y0': [], 'x1': [], 'y1': []};
var cdata = circle.get('data');
var indices = cb_data.index['1d'].indices;

for (i=0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    ind0 = indices[i];
        data['x0'].push(0);
        data['y0'].push(cdata.y[ind0]);
        data['x1'].push(10);
        data['y1'].push(cdata.y[ind0]);

}
segment.set('data', data);
""" 


callback1 = CustomJS(args={'circle': cr1.data_source, 'segment': sr2.data_source}, code=code)
s1.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback1, renderers=[cr1]))

callback2 = CustomJS(args={'circle': cr2.data_source, 'segment': sr2.data_source}, code=code)
s2.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback2, renderers=[cr2]))


# show the results
show(p)
```

Comment: You want a `Span` which is a line that always spans an entire dimension, regardless of what the data range is. You configure its `dimenions` property to set the direction `vertical` or `horizontal` and then you set a single numeric value for `location` (which you could update from the `CustomJS` for instance). It also has an option for CSS rendering mode, which will be much more performant in many cases.

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot.  That was the hint I needed. I posted the functioning code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @bigreddot for his answer on the spans.  I had tried and not gotten in to work, but figured it out with his hints.  The working code is below.  I implemented a span in each plot and then edit the location of each.

```
from bokeh.io import gridplot, show, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Span

output_file('Test.html')

#output_notebook()

x = list(range(11))
y1 = x
y2 = [10 - i for i in x]

# create a new plot
s1 = figure(width=250, plot_height=250, tools="", title=None)
cr1 = s1.circle(x, y1, size=10, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
sp1 = Span(location=source.data['y0'][0], dimension='width', line_color='green',  render_mode='css') 
s1.renderers.extend([sp1,])

# create another one
s2 = figure(width=250, height=250, title=None)
cr2 = s2.triangle(x, y1, size=10, color="firebrick", alpha=0.5)
sp2 = Span(location=source.data['y0'][0], dimension='width', line_color='green', render_mode='css')
s2.renderers.extend([sp2,])

# put all the plots in an HBox
p = gridplot([[s1,s2],[]])

code = """
var cdata = circle.get('data');
var indices = cb_data.index['1d'].indices;

var sum = 0;

for (i=0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    sum += cdata.y[indices[i]];
}

var avg = sum/indices.length
span1.set('location', [avg])
span2.set('location', [avg])
""" 

callback1 = CustomJS(args={'circle': cr1.data_source,  'span1': sp1, 'span2': sp2}, code=code)
s1.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback1, renderers=[cr1]))

callback2 = CustomJS(args={'circle': cr2.data_source, 'span1': sp1, 'span2': sp2}, code=code)
s2.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback2, renderers=[cr2]))

# show the results
show(p)
```