# Dynamically link a Span and a Slider in a python bokeh plot

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to create plots in python using bokeh that allow dynamic visualization of data in bins.  It's worth knowing that I am relatively new to python, very new to bokeh, and I know ZERO javascript.  I have consulted this:

[Link a Span or Cursor in between plots with Bokeh in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032737/link-a-span-or-cursor-in-between-plots-with-bokeh-in-python)

and this:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html

but am having trouble implementing the necessary parts of each.  Here is my code prior to adding the requested capabilities:

```
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider
from bokeh.models import Span, CustomJS

output_file('Raw_Spectra_and_Spillover_Data.html')

# widgets for bin setup
Pix1_LowLow = Slider(start = self.StartDAC, end = self.EndDAC, value = 129, step = 1, title = 'Pixel-1 - Low Bin - Low Thresh')
Pix1_LowHigh = Slider(start = self.StartDAC, end = self.EndDAC, value = 204, step = 1, title = 'Pixel-1 - Low Bin - High Thresh')
Pix1_HighLow = Slider(start = self.StartDAC, end = self.EndDAC, value = 218, step = 1, title = 'Pixel-1 - High Bin - Low Thresh')
Pix1_HighHigh = Slider(start = self.StartDAC, end = self.EndDAC, value = 500, step = 1, title = 'Pixel-1 - High Bin - High Thresh')

plot1spect = figure(width=700, height=250, title='pixel-1 Spectrum')
plot1spect.line(self.SpectDACvals1[0], self.SpectrumData1[0], line_width=2)
plot1spect_LowLowSpan = Span(location=Pix1_LowLow.value, dimension = 'height')
plot1spect_LowHighSpan = Span(location=Pix1_LowHigh.value, dimension = 'height')
plot1spect_HighLowSpan = Span(location=Pix1_HighLow.value, dimension = 'height')
plot1spect_HighHighSpan = Span(location=Pix1_HighHigh.value, dimension = 'height')
plot1spect.renderers.extend([plot1spect_LowLowSpan, plot1spect_LowHighSpan, plot1spect_HighLowSpan, plot1spect_HighHighSpan])

plot1spill = figure(width=700, height=250, title='pixel-1 Spillover')
plot1spill.line(self.SpillDACvals1[0], self.SpillData1[0], line_width=2)
plot1spill_LowLowSpan = Span(location=Pix1_LowLow.value, dimension = 'height')
plot1spill_LowHighSpan = Span(location=Pix1_LowHigh.value, dimension = 'height')
plot1spill_HighLowSpan = Span(location=Pix1_HighLow.value, dimension = 'height')
plot1spill_HighHighSpan = Span(location=Pix1_HighHigh.value, dimension = 'height')
plot1spill.renderers.extend([plot1spill_LowLowSpan, plot1spill_LowHighSpan, plot1spill_HighLowSpan, plot1spill_HighHighSpan])

show(row(plot1spect,plot1spill, widgetbox(Pix1_LowLow, Pix1_LowHigh, Pix1_HighLow, Pix1_HighHigh)))
```

This code gives me this:

[image: Bokeh plot of code above.]

If someone can show me how get `Pix1_LowLow` slider to dynamically control the location of `plot1spect_LowLowSpan`, then I can extend the technique to the other sliders and spans.  Many thanks in advance!

python 3.5.2 - bokeh 12.0

Comment: Please remove the indention in your code. Please put the picture in you question not - as a link. Please use `backticks` for inline code. Please specify your python version.

Comment: Done...  Apologies...

Comment: Would appreciate if you could mark the complete working example I gave as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot.  I fully intend to do as you requested once i have a moment to come back to this task and implement your suggestions.  I should be able to do so later today or tomorrow.  Thanks for all your tutorials as well.  They have been a big help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a minimal complete example. Note that the recommended way to add annotations like `Span` is with `plot.add_layout` as shown below:

```
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import Slider, Span, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

slider = Slider(start=0, end=10, value=3, step=0.1, title='Slider')

plot = figure(width=700, height=250, x_range=(0,10), y_range=(-1, 1))
span = Span(location=slider.value, dimension='height')
plot.add_layout(span)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(span=span), code="""
    span.location = cb_obj.value
""")
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

output_file('span_slider.html')

show(row(plot, widgetbox(slider)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bigreddot for providing the answer.  This is the code that implemented my solution specifically...  Now how to do this programmatically for 128 data files... hmmmm..

```
    from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
    from bokeh.models import Span, CustomJS, Slider

    output_file('Raw_Spectra_and_Spillover_Data.html')

    # widgets for bin setup
    Pix1_LowLow = Slider(start = self.StartDAC, end = self.EndDAC, value = 129, step = 1, title = 'Pixel-1 - Low Bin - Low Thresh')
    Pix1_LowHigh = Slider(start = self.StartDAC, end = self.EndDAC, value = 204, step = 1, title = 'Pixel-1 - Low Bin - High Thresh')
    Pix1_HighLow = Slider(start = self.StartDAC, end = self.EndDAC, value = 218, step = 1, title = 'Pixel-1 - High Bin - Low Thresh')
    Pix1_HighHigh = Slider(start = self.StartDAC, end = self.EndDAC, value = 500, step = 1, title = 'Pixel-1 - High Bin - High Thresh')

    plot1spect = figure(width=700, height=250, title='pixel-1 Spectrum')
    plot1spect.line(self.SpectDACvals1[0], self.SpectrumData1[0], line_width=2)
    plot1spect_LowLowSpan = Span(location=Pix1_LowLow.value, dimension = 'height')
    plot1spect.add_layout(plot1spect_LowLowSpan)
    plot1spect_LowHighSpan = Span(location=Pix1_LowHigh.value, dimension = 'height')
    plot1spect.add_layout(plot1spect_LowHighSpan)
    plot1spect_HighLowSpan = Span(location=Pix1_HighLow.value, dimension = 'height')
    plot1spect.add_layout(plot1spect_HighLowSpan)
    plot1spect_HighHighSpan = Span(location=Pix1_HighHigh.value, dimension = 'height')
    plot1spect.add_layout(plot1spect_HighHighSpan)
    #plot1spect.renderers.extend([plot1spect_LowLowSpan, plot1spect_LowHighSpan, plot1spect_HighLowSpan, plot1spect_HighHighSpan])

    plot1spill = figure(width=700, height=250, title='pixel-1 Spillover')
    plot1spill.line(self.SpillDACvals1[0], self.SpillData1[0], line_width=2)
    plot1spill_LowLowSpan = Span(location=Pix1_LowLow.value, dimension = 'height')
    plot1spill.add_layout(plot1spill_LowLowSpan)
    plot1spill_LowHighSpan = Span(location=Pix1_LowHigh.value, dimension = 'height')
    plot1spill.add_layout(plot1spill_LowHighSpan)
    plot1spill_HighLowSpan = Span(location=Pix1_HighLow.value, dimension = 'height')
    plot1spill.add_layout(plot1spill_HighLowSpan)
    plot1spill_HighHighSpan = Span(location=Pix1_HighHigh.value, dimension = 'height')
    plot1spill.add_layout(plot1spill_HighHighSpan)
    #plot1spill.renderers.extend([plot1spill_LowLowSpan, plot1spill_LowHighSpan, plot1spill_HighLowSpan, plot1spill_HighHighSpan])

    Pix1_LowLow.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(span1 = plot1spect_LowLowSpan,
                                              span2 = plot1spill_LowLowSpan,
                                              slider = Pix1_LowLow),
                                              code = """span1.location = slider.value; span2.location = slider.value""")
    Pix1_LowHigh.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(span1 = plot1spect_LowHighSpan,
                                               span2 = plot1spill_LowHighSpan,
                                               slider = Pix1_LowHigh),
                                               code = """span1.location = slider.value; span2.location = slider.value""")
    Pix1_HighLow.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(span1 = plot1spect_HighLowSpan,
                                               span2 = plot1spill_HighLowSpan,
                                               slider = Pix1_HighLow),
                                               code = """span1.location = slider.value; span2.location = slider.value""")
    Pix1_HighHigh.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(span1 = plot1spect_HighHighSpan,
                                                span2 = plot1spill_HighHighSpan,
                                                slider = Pix1_HighHigh),
                                                code = """span1.location = slider.value; span2.location = slider.value""")
```

Here is a repeat of the plots, but now each slider manipulates the respective span in both plots...

[image]